# Adjoint of the identity is the fractional Laplacian?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, laplacian, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I want to show that the adjoint of the identity $i: H_0^s(\Omega)\rightarrow L^2(\Omega), x\mapsto x$ where $s>0$ is arbitrary is the fractional Laplacian i.e. $(-\Delta)^{s}$ where $(-\Delta)^s$ is defined by measurable functional calculus. We assume $\Omega$ to be open and bounded. Any ideas to support me?

What I know is that if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$ then we could use the definition of $H_0^s(\Omega)$ via Fourrier transform.

But such an definition is not available if $U$ is assumed to be open and bounded.

However I think we one might identify elements in $H_0^s(\Omega)$ via zero extention as elements of $H_0^s(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Just a quick thought: if you can uniquely characterize that adjoint, in a way that allows checking that the fractional power of $\Delta$ satisfies the characterization (via the measurable functional calculus? ... some choices here), you'd have it. Maybe some minor issues about the "extending by $0$" idea, depending on $s$... ?

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you mean by 'adjoint'.

First possibility is to be the adjoint in the sense of dual spaces.
Then $i^*:(L^2)^* \to (H^s)^*$. If one identifies $L^2=(L^2)^*$, then $i^*(f)$ applied to $u\in H^s$ is $i^*(f)(u) = \int_\Omega f\cdot u$.

Second possibility is the Hilbert space adjoint. The definition of $i^*$ is
$\langle i(u),v\rangle_{L^2} = \langle u,i^*(v) \rangle_{H^s}$ for all $u\in H^s$, $v\in L^2$.
In order to compute $v$, one has to solve the variational problem
$$
\langle u,i^*(v) \rangle_{H^s} = \langle i(u),v\rangle_{L^2} = \int_\Omega uv\ dx \quad \forall  u\in H^s.
$$
The left-hand side is the inner product in $H^s$, induced by the fractional Laplacian.
In this sense, $i^*(v) = (-\Delta^s)^{-1}v$.

Comment: Whatever the reason for the downvote was, I expanded the answer.